# How do I update a github fork from the original repo?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull

I forked a github repo.
Now I want to update my fork to the current repo version. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same doubt and found the answer in the [github help](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo).

```
git remote add upstream git://url-to-original
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git push
```

upstream is the name I gave to the original repository.

Hope it helps.